# Retorno do JOIN com valor NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner

Tenho uma tabela com EMPRESA e outra com FILIAL, em uma outra tabela tenho o vinculo do USUÁRIO por EMPRESA e FILIAL ( que é a TB001UXE, caso a filial não esteja na tabela deve considerar todas as filiais da empresa).

O problema que quando faço INNER JOIN o campo esta NULL não aparece as filiais correspondente.

```
SELECT uxe.ca000coduxe, uxe.ce_ca000codusu, uxe.ce_ca000codemp, uxe.ce_ca000codfil, fil.ca000codfil, fil.ce_ca000codemp
FROM sisse.tb001uxe AS uxe
JOIN sisse.tb004fil AS fil
ON
uxe.ce_ca000codemp = fil.ce_ca000codemp
order by ca000coduxe;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo acima o campo CE_CA000CODFIL da terceira linha esta nulo, sendo a empresa 11 (ce_ca000codemp) e na segunda linha foi vinculado a filial 1 (ce_ca000codfil) a filial 3 (ca000codfil) até ai tudo certo, o problema esta quando faço a amarração entre as filiais.

Exemplo: quando faço a amarração das filiais a empresa 11 (ce_ca000codemp - da terceira linha da imagem superior) não aparece mais na consulta.

```
SELECT uxe.ca000coduxe, uxe.ce_ca000codusu, uxe.ce_ca000codemp, uxe.ce_ca000codfil, fil.ca000codfil, fil.ce_ca000codemp
FROM sisse.tb001uxe as uxe
JOIN sisse.tb004fil as fil
ON
uxe.ce_ca000codemp = fil.ce_ca000codemp and
uxe.ce_ca000codfil = fil.ca000codfil
order by ca000coduxe;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei utilizar LEFT JOIN e RIGHT JOIN e não traz o resultado esperado.

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que entendi do resultado que deseja tente:

```
SELECT uxe.ca000coduxe, uxe.ce_ca000codusu, uxe.ce_ca000codemp, uxe.ce_ca000codfil, fil.ca000codfil, fil.ce_ca000codemp
FROM sisse.tb001uxe as uxe 
CROSS JOIN sisse.tb004fil as fil
ON (uxe.ce_ca000codemp = fil.ce_ca000codemp AND ((uxe.ce_ca000codfil = fil.ca000codfil) OR (uxe.ce_ca000codfil IS NULL))
order by ca000coduxe;
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado pela dica!!!!!